# How can I prevent click on drag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-events

I am trying to have an element with both a drag and click event. I have read about and tried a combination of [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

However, no matter what I try, I get a click when drag is *stopped*.

Note, in the MWE this is done on the component itself, but in my actual app I am using `.native` modifier to drag a component

How can I drag without click?

[image: Edit Drag Click]

Component `Draggable`:

```
<template>
  <div
    @pointerdown="handleDown"
    @pointerup="handleUp"
    @pointercancel="handleUp"
    @click="click = !click;"
    :style="style"
    ref="draggableRoot"
    class="draggable"
  >
    drag me!<br />
    am dragged? {{ drag }}<br />
    am clicked? {{ click }}<br />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    style() {
      return {
        left: `${this.x}px`,
        top: `${this.y}px`
      };
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      drag: false,
      click: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleMove({ pageX, pageY, clientX, clientY }) {
      if (this.$refs.draggableRoot) {
        this.x = pageX + this.left;
        this.y = pageY + this.top;
        this.drag = true;
      }
    },
    handleDown(event) {
      const { pageX, pageY } = event;
      const { left, top } = this.$refs.draggableRoot.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.left = left - pageX;
      this.top = top - pageY;
      document.addEventListener("pointermove", this.handleMove);
    },
    handleUp() {
      document.removeEventListener("pointermove", this.handleMove);
      this.drag = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.draggable {
  position: fixed;
  border: solid coral 1px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe that would work:

Add `setTimeout` inside method `handleUp`:

```
handleUp() { 
  document.removeEventListener("pointermove", this.handleMove);
  setTimeout(() => this.drag = false) //this would move this assigment at the end of event queue
}
```

Also add new method `handleClick` and assing it to event `@click`:

```
handleClick() {
  if(!this.drag) { //change click only if not draged
    this.click = !this.click
  }
}
```

[**Seems to work!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkv2jwvll5)

Comment: no idea? maybe they were using Safair? This works in Moz and Chrome. Any idea how to make it work in Safair?

Comment: I've got no way to test it, but maybe try adding very small delay on `setTimeout`, like 50ms. Try `setTimeout(() => this.drag = false, 50)`

Comment: the timeout seems to be ok in Safari it is the drag all together :p. Ill look into it.  In the mean time Ill wait to accept an answer to see if there is a vue native way to solve this :) Thanks for the help tho